# How to sum every couple of consecutive elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of size `(1,10)`:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

Now I want to compute a new array with size `(1,5)` as:

```
B = [3 7 11 15 19]
```

Which is constructed by:

```
3 = 1 + 2
7 = 3 + 4
...
19 = 9 + 10
```

How can I implement it in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You can index the array at every nth element by the syntax `[::n]`

```
a = np.arange(1,11)
a[::2] + a[1::2]
array([ 3,  7, 11, 15, 19])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
How about if A in size (n,m) with  m is an even number m=2k;

Comment: you can index any axis , using the same syntax .  For example `a[:,::2]` will give  every second column and `a[::2,:]` will give every second row.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize the question:

You have an array `A` with size `2n` and you want to get array `B` with size `n` so each element in `B` is the sum of two elements from `A` taken in sequential order.

The easiest solution is to create a for loop with `n` iterations and do the summation for the corresponding elements.

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = np.zeros(shape=(5), dtype=int)

for i in range(len(A) // 2):
  B[i]=(A[2*i] + A[2*i+1])

print(B)
```

You can also use list comprehension:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

B = np.array([A[2*i]+A[2*i+1] for i in range(len(A)//2)])

print(B)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It worked! But now I want to extent to an Array with Size (m,2n). 
How can I do it?

Comment: That's a list answer.  Making arrays will just slow it down.

Comment: @fpga It's quite similar. The "shape" of B will be `(2n - m) // 2` instead. But I agree with @hpaulj - this one is the way of doing it with lists, for arrays @user1319128 's 
 answer might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`A.shape` is (10,), not (1,10).

```
 A.reshape(-1,2)
```

makes a (5,2) array

```
  A.reshape(-1,2).sum(axis=1)
```

sums across columns